# Python's subprocess: How do I hide the terminal window and still capture the output?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

This code works, but a terminal window pops up (briefly):

```
print 'Trying wireless'
while True:
    wlan = subprocess.Popen("netsh wlan connect name='BSD'", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    out, error = wlan.communicate()
    if out.find('success') >=0: break
    print "Still trying wireless..."
    time.sleep(0.5)
print "Connected!"
```

This is Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Any way to stop the pop-up and keep grabbing the output?

Thanks,
Nick.

Comment: have you tried to save the parent script as `.pyw`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a setup for this, but since there are no answers I found something vaguely promising [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor). Can you try this:

```
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW  # tell windows to use wShowWindow options
si.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE  # ShowWindow option - only one that sounded useful
wlan = subprocess.Popen(...., startupinfo=si)  # as before but add the startupinfo argument
```